# Facebook ads network not shown on the android app after signing it with release keys

Tags: android, facebook-ads-api

I have integrated facebooks ads network in my app. When I run the debug version I can see the bottom banner ads whereas when I sign it for release and run the app the ads doesn't load at all.

Please help/advice what could be wrong.

Comment: I have released my first version with the ads, thats working fine, problem is with new update that I want to push to the playstore again.

Answer (score 0):

Hey finally got the solution.

For facebook ads to be shown in the app we have to **add a ad space** in the property defined in the facebooks monetization manager.